# Typescript converting the timestamp into mm-dd format

Tags: angular, typescript, timestamp, angular-pipe

Angular has a pipe for converting a timestamp into a date. I have searched a lot on the web and there is no good solution for this in typescript.

I tried Javascript conversion but didn't get the desired result. I need to get the data in this format **EEEE, MMMM d** which is **Tuesday, January 25** I know we can achieve this using pipes in our template but do not how to get this in typescript.

I tried

```
formatDate(date) {
   let d = new Date(date * 1000)
   return d.getMonth() + 1 + "," + d.getDate
}
```

and used in my code like this

```
for(let i=0; i < this.lessons.length; i++){
      for(let j=1; j< this.lessons.length; j++){
        if(this.formatDate(this.lessons[i].start_time) === this.formatDate(this.lessons[j].start_time)){
          this.data.push({title: this.formatDate(this.lessons[i].start_time), lessons: []})
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(this.data)
  })
```

but no luck all it is coming in my console is like this :

```
{title: "NaN,function getDate() { [native code] }", lessons: Array(0)}
```

Could anyone help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use moment.js instead

Comment: Thanks @mxr7350, but they haven't provided the syntax for conversion of the desired timestamp, all I'm seeing is this moment().format(), do we have any syntax for changing our provided timestamp?

Comment: Scroll down the page and you will find that you can use all different kinds of formats for example format('MM-DD-YYYY') which will output 01-23-2018

Comment: Some people don't want to use Moment (I'm one of them). Angular provides a special class just to do this kind of thing, I don't see why one would need to install moment. Moment is good for making calculations with dates (even though you don't need it), but just for displaying a date, I think using the pipe is way better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, why not use the pipe itslef ?

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
const myFormattedDate = datePipe.transform(this.myTimeStamp, 'EEEE, MMMM d');
```

Comment: Wonderful answer! Got the new thing to learn and I'm thankful to you.

Comment: No problem ! rememebr to mark your issue as resolved :)

Comment: I know this is kinda non sense. But do we have an option of marking an issue as resolved? Couldn't find any.

Comment: I meant, mark an answer as accepted, because it shows you resolved your issue, and in case of several answers, it brings the correct one to the top, avoiding unecessary scrolling.

Comment: Just saw it, but I explained what I meant anyway !